# How to run two servers(application) in play framework 2.2.1 scala language,i using ubuntu 12.04

Tags: scala, ubuntu-12.04, playframework-2.2

individually servers are run well,Please ANY thoughts on this[i created two severs but when i try to run simentaneously it shows this error][1].

i already using running first server as :play run 9000 
2nd sever as play run 9001

is this correct?
[error is coming like this(terminal copy/paste)]
   

    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
        [error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        [error] Total time: 6 s, completed 21 May, 2016 2:56:28 AM

Comment: The error is missing the important part.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to run them on the same port.

Add `-Dhttp.port=9001` to one of them.